# How can I align a green-band and infrared image with openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, infrared

I have two images that I want to align by using openCV. One of the images is a green band of true color imagery, the other is a NIR image of almost the same area (offset is about 180 pixels). For this alignment I want to use python-opencv 3.0 and the ORB algorithm. I use the following script to create the KNNmatches:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('rgb.png',1)
img2 = cv2.imread('nir.png',0)
img1=img1[:,:,1]

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,flags=2,outImg=None)
```

However, when I do that with my images I get just a few matches with the following images:

[image: https://imgur.com/wiYO6Lp]

Would anyone of you know how I could best align these images? Thank you in advance and apologies if this was posted in the wrong forum.

Comment: You may want to look into [Image Registration](http://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/)

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to extract the keypoint locations from your "good matches", as use these to calculate a 3x3 transformation matrix that will transform the corners of one image to the other.

For this case, lets say that we want to transform img2 to align with img1. First we extract locations of good matches:

```
pts1 = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
pts2 = np.float32([kp2[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
```

Then we find the transformation matrix:

```
M = cv2.findHomography(pts2, pts1)
```

Finally, we can apply the transformation:

```
warpedImg2 = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, M, img1.shape)
```

Here is a [great resource](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) on feature detection in OpenCV using Python.

Comment: the main issue is though, that almost no matches were found (3-5 and at the wrong positions). At least way too few for a non-linear transformation.

Comment: Ah ok. Have to tried any other feature detector/descriptor/matcher combinations?  I have had good results using SURF keypoints and descriptors and a FLANN matcher with similar imagery. Another method may be to try a correlation based alignment.